# Tiles insertAttribute Tag Error

Tags: struts2, struts, tiles

I am new to StackOverflow, I am currently working on Tiles in struts2. Every thing coming up without error in the code. But when I run it on server, It tells that:

> javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: Error
>   executing tag: Attribute 'menu' not found.

I added jar files as instucted.
Can anyone help me out??

```
<body>
  <tiles:insertAttribute name="menu"></tiles:insertAttribute>
  <tiles:insertAttribute name="footer"></tiles:insertAttribute>
</body>
}
```

Here is my Tiles.xml...

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><!DOCTYPE tiles-definitions PUBLIC  "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Tiles Configuration 2.0//EN"  "http://tiles.apache.org/dtds/tiles-config_2_0.dtd"><tiles-definitions><definition name="baseLayout" template="/baseLayout.jsp">
  <put-attribute name="title" value="Template"/>
  <put-attribute name="banner" value="/banner.jsp"/>
  <put-attribute name="menu" value="/menu.jsp"/>
  <put-attribute name="body" value="/body.jsp"/>
  <put-attribute name="footer" value="/footer.jsp"/></definition>

 `<definition name="tiger" extends="baseLayout">
  <put-attribute name="title" value="Tiger"/>
  <put-attribute name="body" value="/tiger.jsp"/></definition>    
  <definition name="lion" extends="baseLayout">
  <put-attribute name="title" value="Lion"/>
  <put-attribute name="body" value="/lion.jsp"/> </definition></tiles-definitions>
```

`

Comment: Show your tiles definition.

Comment: And add a stacktrace also.